# Is this function right continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Given a random variable $X$ with density $f$, is the function below right continuous?
$$
F_X(y)=\int_{-\infty}^yxf(x)\ dx.
$$

Comment: $E(X)$ is a number, not a function.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean an integration of a functional form, x*f(x) where f(x) is probability density function, from a constant to some variable y..

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be lots of confusion about several concepts in probability theory.

- First of all, the title is problematic. The expectation of a random variable is *not* defined on Borel sets. It is a real number.
- > "Probability distribution is right continuous".

  What you are really talking about is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)(CDF) of a real-valued random variable $X$.
- > "is it the same with the expectation over the right continuous distribution"

  This sentence does not make sense. [Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) is a concept for random variables. When $X$ has a density $f$, then one has
  $$
  E(X)=\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x)\ dx.
  $$
- > "I mean an integration of a functional form, x*f(x) where f(x) is probability density function, from a constant to some variable y"

  This sentence does not make sense either. Given a random variable $X$ with density $f$, one can write its CDF as
  $$
  F_X(y)=\int_{-\infty}^yf(x)\ dx.
  $$
  $F_X:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is right continuous as a function of $y$. One the other hand, 
  $$
  E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx
  $$
  is a *real number*, assuming $|X|$ has finite expectation.
- > "right continuous"?

  For a function define on a general metric space (or topological space), this concept is meaningless. How can you tell where is right or left in $\mathbb{R}^4$? It only makes when the domain of the function is a subset of the real numbers. For a more general setting, you could take a look at the Wikipedia article about.
  [Semi-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Formal_definition).

What you really want to ask might be the following

> is the expectation operator, as a [linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form#Integration) on the set of all $L^1$ random variables, continuous?

The answer then would be yes.

Comment: Yeah, my question is confusing, I know. So your point is 'continuous', which means not just 'right continuous'?